# Python checking __init__ parameter

Tags: python, class, parameters, init

I've been trying to figuring this out for the last few hours, and I'm about to give up.

How do you make sure that in python only a matching specific criteria will create the object?

For example, let's say I want to create an object Hand, and initialize a Hand only when I have enough Fingers in the initializer?  (Please just take this as an analogy)

Say,

```
class Hand:
  def __init__(self, fingers):
    # make sure len(fingers)==5, and 
    #only thumb, index, middle, ring, pinky are allowed in fingers
    pass
```

Thanks.

These are the closest questions I found, but one is in C++, the other does not answer my question.

[checking of constructor parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361077/checking-of-constructor-parameter)

[How to overload __init__ method based on argument type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141545/overloading-init-in-python)

Comment: What do you want to happen if this is not the case?  Do you want it to raise some sort of exception?

Comment: I guess that would be a good way.  Just to make sure that I don't create a wrong object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define `__new__` for that:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        if arg > 10: #error!
            return None 
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)

print Foo(1)    # <__main__.Foo object at 0x10c903410>
print Foo(100)  # None
```

That said, using `__init__` and raising an exception on invalid args is generally much better:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        if arg > 10: #error!
            raise ValueError("invalid argument!") 
        # do stuff
```

Comment: Defining `__new__` is rarely needed, and returning `None` from it is horrible. Just throw an exception rather than going on for a couple of lines (or a dozen function calls, if you've got bad luck) before crashing with an inexplicable error.

Comment: @delnan - technically, if the OP is serious about "only a matching specific criteria will create the object," defining `__new__` would be needed, because by the time `__init__` is called an object has already been created (still, you're right that raising an exception in `__new__` would be better than returning None).  But I'm guessing the OP doesn't really mean that, in which case the `__init__` version is definitely better.

Comment: @weronika Unless deep magic and awful hackery is involved, raising an exception in `__init__` prevents everyone from getting a reference to the not-really-constructed object. So from an observer's POV there's no difference beside one being a terrible API.

Answer (score 0):

Try asserting:

```
class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self,fingers):
        assert len(fingers) == 5
        for fing in ("thumb","index","middle","ring","pinky"):
            assert fingers.has_key(fing)
```

Comment: No, `assert` is for verifying *internal* invariants: Checking that *your* code isn't horribly broken. `AssertionError` conveys no useful information to the caller, and may make her think your code is broken. Besides, assertions are stripped by `-O`. Throw a `ValueError` or `RuntimeError` or whatever is appropriate for the specific use case.